# Is it possible to allow (or extend) IO connectors so they can read previous PCollection items?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Question may not be as clear as I would want to but it's complicated to explain at first what I'm trying to achieve in here.

Having a Window, is it possible to make "smaller" windows out of a global one and trigger each of those windows individually? A bit of pseudocode to clear the waters a bit.

```
        pipeline
                .apply("InputStream", stream)
                .apply("3600s windowDuration",
                        Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(3600)))
                )
                .apply("/// groupBy 'timestamp, store_id and collection_name'? ///", ...)
                .apply("Write to MongoDB",
                        MongoDbIO
                                .write()
                                .withCollection(msg -> msg.getCollection()) // Admits a String but doesn't admit reading from the previous typed PCollection.
                );
```

Is it possible to apply MongoDB writes based on message data? Or at least configure the class to do so? Seems impossible at first so I don't know if there's any other Beam-related workaround which may work to allow multiple insertions.

My idea would be to have smaller inner windows inside the global 3600s one and then apply insertions after that. Kind of something what `FileIO` does with its `.by` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understand correctly, you would like to write to a Mongo collection depending on the collection listed on the object, right?

Unfortunately, it looks that it is not possible at the moment (see [Javadoc for MongoDBIO](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/mongodb/MongoDbIO.html)).

If the list of collections is relatively small, and known *a priori*, then you could route events to multiple `MongoDBIO.write` transforms, but that may not be possible. Something kind of like this:

```
myelements.apply(
          Filter.by(msg -> msg.getCollection().equals(COLLECTION1))
          .apply("Write to MongoDB - coll1",
                        MongoDbIO
                                .write()
                                .withCollection(COLLECTION1));

myelements.apply(
          Filter.by(msg -> msg.getCollection().equals(COLLECTION2))
          .apply("Write to MongoDB - coll2",
                        MongoDbIO
                                .write()
                                .withCollection(COLLECTION2));
```

If that would not work for you, then you may need to write your own logic to write to MongoDB. If you need to write your own, I recommend you use [`GroupIntoBatches`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/GroupIntoBatches.html) to create batches of elements for each MongoDB collection, and write those out.

Answer (score 0):

The "collection" in the withCollection function is a MongoDB term, unrelated to Beam's PCollections.

The MongoDbIO.write transform will just write the contents of its input PCollection out to MongoDB.  You can apply it to any PCollection in your pipeline, and you can freely change the windowing inside your pipeline as well.